# Vue 3 + Typescript emit function "No overload matches this call" even if the function name is defined. It looks like order matters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli, vuejs3

I found a weird error message in Vue 3 emit function when i use it with TypeScript.
example code to reproduce:

```
export default defineComponent({
  emits: {
    emit1: (payload: number) => payload,
    emit2: (payload: string) => payload
  },
  methods: {
   ...
  }
}
```

when i try to call the emit1 like the following, it compiles without an error:
`this.$emit("emit1", 1);`

but if i do the following there is weird error:
`this.$emit("emit1", "test");`

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"emit1"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"emit2"'.
```

if i change the order of the emit functions like so:

```
export default defineComponent({
  emits: {
    emit2: (payload: string) => payload,
    emit1: (payload: number) => payload
  },
  methods: {
   ...
  }
}
```

Of course also a error appears, but this one make more sense at least:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

since the function name is defined in both cases the error message #1 makes no sense but #2 does.

My Questions:

- why does the order of the functions has an impact on the error message?
- should / can this be fixed in vue so that the error makes sense in both cases? Mybe this is also a issue with TypeScript itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the latest Vue CLI version, here is the full error received with either `emit` order.  When switching the order of the emits, it still shows both error messages, just in reverse order:

```js
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(event: "emit1", payload: number): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

  Overload 2 of 2, '(event: "emit2", payload: string): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"emit1"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"emit2"'.
```

This makes it quite clear what's happening, though since you could only see one of the messages it was very confusing:

- Vue is testing the emit against all potentially matching `emits` entries (i.e. the overloads).  Both the emit name you use in the method and the emit value are provided as parameters to the testing function.  That's where you see `event`, `payload` passed as arguments.
- With one overload, the `event` parameter has a match but the `value` parameter causes a type error.  With the other, there is no `event` match.